# How to remove rounded border from highlighted text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wanted to know how to remove this rounded border from highlighting text:

[image: See it here]

Comment: does it change with the Theme

Comment: Nope, even on the default theme it is rounded.

Comment: If you disable all extensions is it still rounded?

Comment: Yep, still rounded.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, it was a simple fix:

```
    "editor.roundedSelection": false,
```

This setting defaulted to true from a recent update, hope this helps :)